# How to open a folder windows in java aplication ? I want to insert path of file .txt in my application

Tags: java, path, window, directory

How to make a button that can open folder option and search .txt file.
I want to insert path (example : `c:/documents`) by open window if folder option. so the user of my aplication just click it and not type it in the field text.
by the way I use netbeans as my IDE.
please help me. thank you.

Comment: Something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with JFileChooser. [Official Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) is the best place to start.

Important steps are:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    //This is where a real application would open the file.
    log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
} else {
    log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
}
```